# How I Can I add a code behind to a layout page using web parts

Tags: sharepoint-designer, web-part, page-layout

I am following this link on how to create  metadata navigation :-

http://markuspersson.wordpress.com/2012/01/19/add-metadata-navigation-on-custom-page-layouts/

so I added the references for the navigation , but now I want to know where I should add the following code:-

```
public class CustomWikiPageBase : PublishingLayoutPage
{
    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["TreeField"]) 
            && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["TreeValue"]))
        {
            Response.Redirect(String.Format("{0}?TreeField={1}&TreeValue={2}",
                SPContext.Current.ListItem.ParentList.DefaultViewUrl,
                Request.QueryString["TreeField"],
                Request.QueryString["TreeValue"]));
        }
        else if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["TreeField"]))
        {
            Response.Redirect(String.Format("{0}?TreeField={1}",
                SPContext.Current.ListItem.ParentList.DefaultViewUrl,
                Request.QueryString["TreeField"]));
        }
        base.OnInit(e);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to add this code on a web part? If yes then what type of web part it should be ? and could I do this using SharePoint designer?

BR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in a regular web part (don't need a visual web part).  Just put the OnInit override method in the web part code.

Comment: i tried overriding the Oninit method , but it raised the following error inside Visual Studio :- Error 2 The name 'Request' does not exist in the current context.

Comment: You can use HttpContext.Current.Request and HttpContext.Current.Response.